# Zebra CURL not improving execution time

Tags: php, curl

I need to send around 500 CURL requests to an API so I went for Zebra_CURL to reduce execution time but this didn't improve anything:

```
$curl = new Zebra_cURL();
$curl->threads = 30;

$curl->option(array(
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER =>  TRUE,
  CURLOPT_HEADER =>  FALSE,
  CURLOPT_POST =>  TRUE,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json','Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("XX:YY")
    ),
  )); 

for ($i=0; $i < count($recipients); $i++){

  $curl->post(array(
  'API_URL'  => 'To=XXXXX&From=YYYY&Body=ZZZZ'
  ));
}
```

Did I miss something? Or am I supposed to do only one `$curl->post` ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: the speed really depends on how fast the server acknowledges your request also.

Comment: Hi! Yes I guess so but does the way I use it seems correct to you? I have a feeling I should just have one $curl->post with all the requests as the loop is waiting for the callback to execute the second one, no? Really not sure I implemented it correctly...

Comment: you are right, your code uses `for` and did not use Zebra's [queue](https://stefangabos.github.io/Zebra_cURL/Zebra_cURL/Zebra_cURL.html#methodqueue) feature so its called immediately which means costly. perhaps, calling `queue()` before `for` loop and [`start()`](https://stefangabos.github.io/Zebra_cURL/Zebra_cURL/Zebra_cURL.html#methodstart) after the loop done is best.

Comment: And that should be the answer as it just went from 120-140 seconds to 10 seconds, so thanks a lot!